# Pop up and move image to another location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get an image to 'pop up' on screen and then animate this image as if it's going into another container. So when a link is clicked an image flies up the page, here's my link:

```
<a href="#" data-image="/media/1008/aquaberry.jpg" class="wishlistAdd" id="1161">Click me</a>
```

with the div at the top of the page being having a class of wishlist (for some reason I can't post the HTML!)

So in my click function I have:

```
var myImage = $(this).attr("data-image");
var myWishList = $('.wishlist');
var image = $('<img width="30px" height="30px" src="' + myImage + '"/>').css({
    "position": "fixed",
    "z-index": "999"
});

myWishList.prepend(image);
var position = myWishList.position();

image.animate({
    top: position.top,
    left: position.left
}, 500, "linear", function () {
    image.remove();
});
```

So I'm trying to get the image to pop up and 'fly' to the top of the page and disappear.

I get no errors in the console but nothing actually happens on screen. Could someone tell me the error of my ways, please?

Thanks,
C

Comment: The complete code might help.

Comment: That is the complete code

Comment: @SxChoc try and use an `HTML\CSS\JS` snippet so people can visually see what you have and what you're trying to do. that might help people answer your question

Comment: As the image is `position:fixed`, its position is relative to the viewport, so you can't really prepend it to an element.

Answer (score 0):

When you prepend your image, it's appearing in its "final" location already, so there's nowhere for it to animate to.
To fix this, you could add a `bottom: 0` and `right: 0` or `left: 0` to your images CSS.

For example:

```
var image = $('<img width="30px" height="30px" src="' + myImage + '"/>').css({
    "position": "fixed",
    "bottom": "0",
    "right": "30px", //width of your image
    "z-index": "999"
});
```

If you wanted your image to slide onto the screen instead of appearing, you would set

`bottom: -30px //height of your image`

[Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PatTastic/b088jauv/1/)